# Webpack build stuck in Jenkins pipeline during assets optimization

Tags: angular, jenkins, webpack, jenkins-pipeline

I use `webpack` for development and build purpose for my `Angular2` app.

When building my sources (`webpack --profile --bail`) on my machine the webpack process finishes normally.
When using the same command **in my Jenkins CI pipeline** the process gets **stuck for ever in assets optimization**, supposedly after using the `html-webpack-plugin` or before using the `extract-text-webpack-plugin`.

Here are the steps in the Jenkins pipeline:

```
container(name: 'webpack'){
  git 'http://gogs/SMITE/smite-gui-manager.git'

  echo 'Installing node modules'
  sh 'npm install'
  echo 'Building application to /dist'
  sh 'rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail --verbose'

  stage 'Canary release'
  newVersion = performCanaryRelease {}
}
```

The container used contains the needed binaries, and the above steps should install all the needed `node_modules`, so the build environments SHOULD be the same.

---

Here are the different outputs :

On my machine:

```
[...]

Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    Asset    Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    index.html  544 kB       0  
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
       [0] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [depth 1] [built]
           cjs require ./../../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js [3] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/public/index.html 1:8-89
           [] -> factory:205ms building:2526ms = 2731ms
       [1] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [depth 2] [built]
           cjs require global [0] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/~/lodash/lodash.js 1:0-47
           [] -> factory:395ms building:408ms = 803ms
       [2] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [depth 2] [built]
           cjs require module [0] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/~/lodash/lodash.js 1:0-47
           [] -> factory:395ms building:409ms = 804ms
       [3] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/public/index.html 873 bytes {0} [depth 0] [built]
            factory:31ms building:22ms = 53ms

Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
    Asset     Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    fonts/icons.25a32416abee198dd821b0b17a198a8f.eot?  76.5 kB          
    fonts/icons.d7c639084f684d66a1bc66855d193ed8.svg?   392 kB          
    fonts/icons.1dc35d25e61d819a9c357074014867ab.ttf?   153 kB          
    fonts/icons.c8ddf1e5e5bf3682bc7bebf30f394148.woff?  90.4 kB          
    fonts/icons.e6cf7c6ec7c2d6f670ae9d762604cb0b.woff2?  71.9 kB          
    fonts/flags.9c74e172f87984c48ddf5c8108cabe67.png?  28.1 kB          
    Entrypoint undefined = extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename
       [0] ./semantic/dist/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.eot 95 bytes {0} [depth 1] [built]
           cjs require ./themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.eot [7] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./semantic/dist/semantic.css 6:151450-151500
           cjs require ./themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.eot [7] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./semantic/dist/semantic.css 6:151523-151573
           [] -> factory:6ms building:1ms = 7ms
       [1] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [depth 1] [built]
           cjs require ./../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js [7] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./semantic/dist/semantic.css 1:27-85
           [] -> factory:5ms building:2ms = 7ms
       [2] ./semantic/dist/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.svg 95 bytes {0} [depth 1] [built]
           cjs require ./themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.svg [7] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./semantic/dist/semantic.css 6:151871-151921
           [] -> factory:6ms building:3ms = 9ms
       [3] ./semantic/dist/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.ttf 95 bytes {0} [depth 1] [built]
           cjs require ./themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.ttf [7] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./semantic/dist/semantic.css 6:151787-151837
           [] -> factory:6ms building:2ms = 8ms
       [4] ./semantic/dist/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff 96 bytes {0} [depth 1] [built]
           cjs require ./themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff [7] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./semantic/dist/semantic.css 6:151706-151757
           [] -> factory:6ms building:2ms = 8ms
       [5] ./semantic/dist/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff2 97 bytes {0} [depth 1] [built]
           cjs require ./themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff2 [7] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./semantic/dist/semantic.css 6:151623-151675
           [] -> factory:6ms building:2ms = 8ms
       [6] ./semantic/dist/themes/default/assets/images/flags.png 95 bytes {0} [depth 1] [built]
           cjs require ./themes/default/assets/images/flags.png [7] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./semantic/dist/semantic.css 6:115925-115976
           [] -> factory:6ms building:1ms = 7ms
       [7] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./semantic/dist/semantic.css 732 kB {0} [depth 0] [built]
            factory:4ms building:2719ms = 2723ms

Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
    Entrypoint undefined = extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename
       [0] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [depth 1] [built]
           cjs require ./../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js [1] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/style/app.scss 1:27-85
           [] -> factory:0ms building:1ms = 1ms
       [1] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/style/app.scss 2.41 kB {0} [depth 0] [built]
            factory:12ms building:2793ms = 2805ms

>>> BUILD FINISHED WITHOUT ERROR <<<<
```

On the Jenkins builder :

```
[...]

Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    Asset     Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    index.html  1.45 MB       0  
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
       [0] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [depth 1] [built]
           cjs require ./../../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js [3] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/public/index.html 1:8-56
           [] -> factory:522ms building:5253ms = 5775ms
       [1] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [depth 2] [built]
           cjs require global [0] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 1:0-41
           [] -> factory:348ms building:833ms = 1181ms
       [2] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [depth 2] [built]
           cjs require module [0] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 1:0-41
           [] -> factory:348ms building:834ms = 1182ms
       [3] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/public/index.html 840 bytes {0} [depth 0] [built]

>>> STUCK HERE FOR EVER <<<
```

---

Just in case, here are the dependencies listed in my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^2.4.3",
    "angular2-logger": "^0.5.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "core-js": "~2.4.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "jquery": "~3.1.1",
    "ng2-semantic-ui": "~0.4.7",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-ldapauth": "^1.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~5.1.0",
    "semantic-ui": "~2.2.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.29",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.4",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.39",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.18",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.4.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "protractor": "^5.1.0",
    "pug-html-loader": "^1.0.9",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.8.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslint": "^4.4.2",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.1",
    "typescript": "2.1.5",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.9"
  }
```

And my webpack config :

```
// Helper: root() is defined at the bottom
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

// Webpack Plugins
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
var ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;

/**
 * Env
 * Get npm lifecycle event to identify the environment
 */
var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isTestWatch = ENV === 'test-watch';
var isTest = ENV === 'test' || isTestWatch;
var isProd = ENV === 'build';

module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {
    /**
     * Config
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html
     * This is the object where all configuration gets set
     */
    var config = {};

    /**
     * Devtool
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
     * Type of sourcemap to use per build type
     */
    if (isProd) {
        config.devtool = 'source-map';
    }
    else if (isTest) {
        config.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
    }
    else {
        config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
    }

    /**
     * Entry
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
     */
    config.entry = isTest ? {} : {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts' // our angular app
    };

    /**
     * Output
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
     */
    config.output = isTest ? {} : {
        path: root('dist'),
        publicPath: isProd ? '/' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: isProd ? 'js/[name].[hash].js' : 'js/[name].js',
        chunkFilename: isProd ? '[id].[hash].chunk.js' : '[id].chunk.js'
    };

    /**
     * Resolve
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
     */
    config.resolve = {
        // only discover files that have those extensions
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],
    };

    var atlOptions = '';
    if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
        // awesome-typescript-loader needs to output inlineSourceMap for code coverage to work with source maps.
        atlOptions = 'inlineSourceMap=true&sourceMap=false';
    }

    /**
     * Loaders
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
     * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html
     * This handles most of the magic responsible for converting modules
     */
    config.module = {
        rules: [
            // Support for .ts files.
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader?' + atlOptions, 'angular2-template-loader', '@angularclass/hmr-loader'],
                exclude: [isTest ? /\.(e2e)\.ts$/ : /\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
            },

            // copy those assets to output
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]?'
            },

            // Support for *.json files.
            {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},

            // Support for CSS as raw text
            // use 'null' loader in test mode (https://github.com/webpack/null-loader)
            // all css in src/style will be bundled in an external css file
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: root('src', 'app'),
                loader: isTest ? 'null-loader' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader']})
            },
            // all css required in src/app files will be merged in js files
            {test: /\.css$/, include: root('src', 'app'), loader: 'raw-loader!postcss-loader'},

            // support for .scss files
            // use 'null' loader in test mode (https://github.com/webpack/null-loader)
            // all css in src/style will be bundled in an external css file
            {
                test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
                exclude: root('src', 'app'),
                loader: isTest ? 'null-loader' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']})
            },
            // all css required in src/app files will be merged in js files
            {test: /\.(scss|sass)$/, exclude: root('src', 'style'), loader: 'raw-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader'},

            // support for .html as raw text
            // todo: change the loader to something that adds a hash to images
            {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader',  exclude: root('src', 'public')},

            {test: /\.(pug|jade)$/, loader: 'pug-html-loader',  exclude: root('src', 'public')}
        ]
    };

    if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
        // instrument only testing sources with Istanbul, covers ts files
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.ts$/,
            enforce: 'post',
            include: path.resolve('src'),
            loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
            exclude: [/\.spec\.ts$/, /\.e2e\.ts$/, /node_modules/]
        });
    }

    if (!isTest || !isTestWatch) {
        // tslint support
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.ts$/,
            enforce: 'pre',
            loader: 'tslint-loader'
        });
    }

    /**
     * Plugins
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html
     */
    config.plugins = [

        // Exposes jQuery librairy
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        }),

        // Define env variables to help with builds
        // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            // Environment helpers
            'process.env': {
                ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV)
            }
        }),

        // Workaround needed for angular 2 angular/angular#11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            root('./src') // location of your src
        ),

        // Tslint configuration for webpack 2
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                /**
                 * Apply the tslint loader as pre/postLoader
                 * Reference: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
                 */
                tslint: {
                    emitErrors: false,
                    failOnHint: false
                },
                /**
                 * Sass
                 * Reference: https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader
                 * Transforms .scss files to .css
                 */
                sassLoader: {
                    //includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss")]
                },
                /**
                 * PostCSS
                 * Reference: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core
                 * Add vendor prefixes to your css
                 */
                postcss: [
                    autoprefixer({
                        browsers: ['last 2 version']
                    })
                ]
            }
        })
    ];

    if (!isTest && !isProd) {
        config.plugins.push(new DashboardPlugin());
    }

    if (!isTest && !isTestWatch) {
        config.plugins.push(
            //new ForkCheckerPlugin(),

            // Generate common chunks if necessary
            // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html
            // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
            new CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
            }),

            // Inject script and link tags into html files
            // Reference: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './src/public/index.html',
                chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
            }),

            // Extract css files
            // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
            // Disabled when in test mode or not in build mode
            new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'css/[name].[hash].css', disable: !isProd})
        );
    }

    // Add build specific plugins
    if (isProd) {
        config.plugins.push(
            // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#noerrorsplugin
            // Only emit files when there are no errors
            new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),

            // // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dedupeplugin
            // // Dedupe modules in the output
            // new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

            // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin
            // Minify all javascript, switch loaders to minimizing mode
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({sourceMap: true, mangle: { keep_fnames: true }}),

            // Copy assets from the public folder
            // Reference: https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
                from: root('src/public')
            }])
        );
    }

    /**
     * Dev server configuration
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devserver
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html
     */
    config.devServer = {
        contentBase: './src/public',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        quiet: true,
        stats: 'minimal', // none (or false), errors-only, minimal, normal (or true) and verbose

        /**
         * Proxy
         * http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy
         * Used to delegate one or multiple path to another server
         */
        proxy: {
            '/api' : {
                target: 'http://localhost:3333',
                secure: false
            }
        }
    };

    return config;
}();

// Helper functions
function root(args) {
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
}
```

---

I couldn't get any additional logs despite the use of the `--verbose` option, and can't find a way to fix the bug, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the version of node was the culprit!

I ran a nodejs debugger and didn't find any additional info but I tried to build with different versions of node, and bingo!

As weird as it may seem, node v6.9.0 and v.6.9.1 (the npm dependency in yum repos) didn't behave the same (it's a minor version change, come on !).

Installing node v7.5.0 on both environments did the trick !